# Django - how to sort/order multiple objects by multiple fields?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I want to display a music album on my website, the Problem is that the album itself has two discs and each disc has x tracks. Now I'm wondering how I can display this split-up on my Django template as I want it to look like that:

```
Disc 1
   - Title - 1
   - Title - 2
   - Title - 3
   - Title - 4
   ...
Disc 2
   - Title - 1
   - Title - 2
   - Title - 3
   - Title - 4
   ...
```

This is my View:

```
def music_album_detail(request, pk):
    music_album = get_object_or_404(MusicAlbums, pk=pk)
    music_album_tracks = MusicTracks.objects.filter(album=music_album).order_by('track')
    args = {
        'music_album': music_album,
        'music_album_tracks': music_album_tracks,
    }
    return render(request, 'App/music_album_detail.html', args)
```

At my Template I currently only do this:

```
{% for music_album_track in music_album_tracks %}
  <td>{{ music_album_track.track }}</td>
  ...
```

This is how my model looks like:

```
class MusicAlbums(models.Model):
    objects = RandomManager()
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Title"), blank=False, null=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(MusicArtists, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='album_artist')
    cover = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Cover"), blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_file_path_images)
    cover_tn = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Cover Thumbnail"), blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_file_path_images)
    release_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Release Date"), blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    genre_relation = models.ManyToManyField(through='GenreMusicAlbum', to='Genre')
    total_discs = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Total Discs #"), blank=True, null=True,)
    total_tracks = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Total Tracks #"), blank=True, null=True,)
    copyright = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Copyright"), blank=True, null=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Date Added"))


class MusicTracks(models.Model):
    objects = RandomManager()
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    file = models.ForeignKey(Files, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='track_file')
    bitrate = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Bitrate (bps)"), blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    duration = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_("Duration"), blank=True, null=True, editable=False, max_length=255)
    size = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Size (byte)"))
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Title"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(MusicArtists, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='track_artist')
    album = models.ForeignKey(MusicAlbums, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='track_album')
    release_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Release Date"), blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    disc = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Disc #"), blank=True, null=True,)
    track = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Track #"), blank=True, null=True,)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Date Added"))
```

Any Idea how I can setup such a depiction at my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the queryset by `disc` first, and then by `track`:

```
MusicTracks.objects.filter(album=music_album).order_by('disc', 'track')
```

This will order all the tracks in the album by the disc number, and then by the tracks within those discs.

**EDIT**:

To display them by disc, you can do something like this:

```
def music_album_detail(request, pk):
    music_album = get_object_or_404(MusicAlbums, pk=pk)
    music_album_tracks_by_disc = {}

    for track in MusicTracks.objects.filter(album=music_album).order_by('track'):
        if track.disk in music_album_tracks_by_disc:
            music_album_tracks_by_disc[track.disk].append(track)
        else:
            music_album_tracks_by_disc[track.disk] = [track]

    context = {
        'music_album': music_album,
        'music_album_tracks_by_disc': music_album_tracks_by_disc,
    }
    return render(request, 'App/music_album_detail.html', context=context)
```

```
{% for disc, tracks in music_album_tracks_by_disc.items %}
  <td>Disc {{ disc }}</td>
  {% for track in tracks %}
    <td>{{ track.track }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use disc in another model and set FK for that:

```py
class MusicAlbums(models.Model):
    ...

class MusicDiscs(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(...)
    number = models.IntegerField(...) # For example 

class MusicTracks(models.Model):
    disc = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

Now in this way, every album has few discs, and every disc has it's tracks

And now you can get discs in your view, and pass it with it's tracks to template:

```
def music_album_detail(request, pk):
    music_album_discs = Musicdiscs.objects.filter(...)
```

and in your templates:

```
{% for music_disc in music_album_discs %}
  <td>{{ music_disc.number }}</td>
  {% for music_track in music_album_tracks %}
    <td>{{ music_track.track }}</td>
```

Comment: Okay I understand the first part of you solution and I also first thought this is the whole picture but how to you prevent that you show all track for each disc? currently I get all tracks for each disc. But I want to have only the tracks that belong to the specific disc